# Xubuntu Desktop

Tags: xubuntu

I can not add applications to desktop. He says they already exist but I do not see them. Maybe I've been able to use xfce panel but in no case it lets me add applications says they are already

I'm new to xubuntu

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English Only website.  Please only post in English on this website, or use a translation service such as Google Translate when posting.

Comment: Please edit your question title to reflect the question/problem.